# Dynamic Variable in Jquery, Select element with ID same as value of actual element

Tags: jquery

How can one access an element which has for ID the value (.val()) of a active element?

```
<dt>KEY</dt>
<dd id="KEY">Bla Bla Value</dd>
<dt>KEY2</dt>
<dd id="KEY2">Bla Bla Value</dd>
```

Suppose that in the prior case, once the .click action is fired for DT with value KEY, I need to execute an action on DD with ID same Key (same as the value of the active element).

**UPDATE**
There different solutions. The accepted one is not working on all browsers, please check below for the solution presented by Irvin and his modification to use data-key instead of ID for dd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
$('dt').on('click', function(e) {
    var dd = $('#' + this.innerText);
    // do something with dd
});
```

Comment: Firefox doesn't support the `.innerText` property. Maybe `# + (this.innerText || this.textContent)`.

Comment: @BlackSheep and rightfully so, it's non-standard. He is looking for the standard `.textContnet`

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, it's non-standard, And not surprisingly IE8 and below do no support the `textContent`.

Comment: Which is why `$(this).text()` should probably be used. Also, this question is horrible and assigning IDs like this is a bad idea, but that's unrelated :D\

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Yes, and based on the markup `$(this).next()` selects the target elements :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use an [`attribute equal selector`](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/) and check the id:

> Selects elements that have the specified attribute with a value
>   exactly equal to a certain value.

Instead of get the text of the element you can set a custom attribute (eg. `data-key`) and use it as a filter on the selector.

Code:

```
$("body").on("click", "#main-container dt", function () {
    $(this).siblings("dd[id='"+$(this).data("key")+"']").toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EFb4X/5/

### UPDATE

The first solution is good fo filter custom attributes, since you want to filter the element ID Instead of an attribute selector you can use a direct id selector like:

```
$("body").on("click", "#main-container dt", function () {
    $('#'+$(this).data("key")).toggle();
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/EFb4X/6/

Comment: Why would you use an attribute equals selector when there's already a specific jQuery selector for IDs?

Answer (score 2):

This would work:

```
$("dt").click(function() {

    // Change font color to red
    $("dd#" + $(this).html()).css({'color' : 'red'});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```
$(document).on('click', 'dt', function() {
    var clicked_ele = $(this).text();
    $('dd[id=' + clicked_ele +']').trigger('click');  //performing click action on the dd with same key val as id
});
```